# I wan to access my php file in this format httP://Ip address /test.php through docker file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Here is my dockerfile code Plus i am new in this domain

FROM ubuntu
#FROM wordpress:latest

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -y

RUN apt-get install apache2 -y

RUN apt-get install php -y

RUN apt-get install php-mysql -y

ADD dir.conf /etc/apache2/mods-enabled

ADD test.php /http://localhost/test.php

CMD apachectl -D FOREGROUND

and i save my test.php file in  root/wordpress/code directory.

Thanks in advance

I tried to access my test.php page from dockerfile
here is my composer file code

```
version: "3.9"  # optional since v1.27.0
services:
  web:
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    build:
      context: ./code
```

Comment: What URL are you trying to access?  What happens when you call it?  What is your host OS and Docker environment?

Comment: The URL I want to access http://localhost/test.php and the error I got is 404 not found and I used Ubuntu.

Comment: Your last `ADD` line copies your source file into a directory named `/http:` in the root of the container filesystem.  Do you need to put it somewhere like `/var/www/html` instead?

Comment: (If you are using native Ubuntu without Docker Desktop, and `docker-compose up` works successfully, and you're specifically getting an HTTP 404 error, then the Docker-level networking setup is correct, but the Apache inside the container isn't finding the file to serve.)

Comment: My test.php file path is /root/WordPress/code I make these 2 directors is it necessary to put my files in HTML folder ?